# PostgreSQL: FULL OUTER JOIN on RANGE datatypes

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-performance

I have several tables with partially overlapping `TSTZRANGE` values and I need to `JOIN` them such that "breakpoints" are created for each `UPPER` and `LOWER` boundary for each range.

**Some sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    foo TEXT,
    active_timespan TSTZRANGE
);
INSERT INTO 
    foo (foo, active_timespan)
VALUES
    ('One',TSTZRANGE('2015-01-01 00:00:00-00','2015-01-01 06:00:00-00')),
    ('Two',TSTZRANGE('2015-01-01 12:00:00-00','2015-01-01 18:00:00-00'));

CREATE TABLE bar (
    bar_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    bar TEXT,
    active_timespan TSTZRANGE
);
INSERT INTO 
    bar (bar, active_timespan)
VALUES
    ('Alpha',TSTZRANGE('2015-01-01 03:00:00-00','2015-01-01 09:00:00-00')),
    ('Bravo',TSTZRANGE('2015-01-01 15:00:00-00','2015-01-01 21:00:00-00'));
```

**Desired Result:**

```
active_timespan                                       | foo  | bar
------------------------------------------------------|------|------
'["2015-01-01 00:00:00-00","2015-01-01 03:00:00-00"]' | One  | Null
'["2015-01-01 03:00:00-00","2015-01-01 06:00:00-00"]' | One  | Alpha
'["2015-01-01 06:00:00-00","2015-01-01 09:00:00-00"]' | Null | Alpha
'["2015-01-01 12:00:00-00","2015-01-01 15:00:00-00"]' | Two  | Null
'["2015-01-01 15:00:00-00","2015-01-01 18:00:00-00"]' | Two  | Bravo
'["2015-01-01 18:00:00-00","2015-01-01 21:00:00-00"]' | Null | Bravo
```

**Current approach:**

I currently use an elaborate system of `cte`'s where I select the data I want from each table into it's own `cte` and then `UNION` all the the distinct `UPPER` and `LOWER` range values from each query, leaving me with a list of `TIMESTAMPTZ` values. I then use a `LEAD` window function to make new `TSTZRANGE` values. Once I have all that complete I join the original `cte` to the new list of `TSTZRANGE` values.

### Update

Current query pattern below:

```
WITH
    cte_foo AS (
        SELECT
            foo_id,
            foo,
            active_timespan
        FROM
            foo
        WHERE
            active_timespan && $1
    )
    , cte_bar AS (
        SELECT
            bar_id,
            bar,
            active_timespan
        FROM
            bar
        WHERE
            active_timespan && $1
    )
--  continue for each table to be joined... 
--  , cte_baz AS (
--      SELECT
--          baz_id,
--          baz,
--          active_timespan
--      FROM
--          baz
--      WHERE
--          active_timespan && $1
--  )
    , cte_times AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            UNNEST(
                ARRAY[
                    LOWER(cte_foo.active_timespan),
                    UPPER(cte_foo.active_timespan)
                ]
            ) AS breakpoint
        FROM
            cte_foo

        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
            UNNEST(
                ARRAY[
                    LOWER(cte_bar.active_timespan),
                    UPPER(cte_bar.active_timespan)
                ]
            ) AS breakpoint
        FROM
            cte_bar

--      continue for each table to be joined... 
--      UNION
--      SELECT DISTINCT
--          UNNEST(
--              ARRAY[
--                  LOWER(cte_baz.active_timespan),
--                  UPPER(cte_baz.active_timespan)
--              ]
--          ) AS breakpoint
--      FROM
--          cte_baz
    )
    , cte_timespans AS (
        SELECT
            TSTZRANGE(
                sub_times.breakpoint,
                LEAD(sub_times.breakpoint, 1, 'infinity'::TIMESTAMPTZ) OVER (ORDER BY sub_times.breakpoint)
            ) AS timespan
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    cte_times.breakpoint
                FROM
                    cte_times
            ) AS sub_times
        ORDER BY
            timespan
    )
SELECT
    cte_timespans.timespan,
    cte_foo.foo,
    cte_bar.bar
FROM
    cte_timespans
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_foo ON cte_timespans.timespan && cte_foo.active_timespan
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_bar ON cte_timespans.timespan && cte_bar.active_timespan

--  continue for each table to be joined...
--  LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_baz ON cte_timespans.timespan && cte_baz.active_timespan
ORDER BY
    cte_timelines.timespan
```

Performance is obviously poor, especially when I am joining several tables (over ten in some cases). Is this the best way to approach this situation?

**Wishful thinking:**

It would be great if PostgreSQL had some kind of `RANGE JOIN` - something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    foo
    FULL OUTER RANGE JOIN bar ON foo.active_timespan && bar.active_timespan
```

Comment: "*Performance is obviously poor,*" I don't see any proof that in your question. Please read: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and supply the execution plan (use `explain analyze`) on your real world data. The range data type can also be indexed: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING Did you try that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the performance takes a hit due to the nature of the `cte` (described as "optimization fences" in the documentation). They also remove all indices after the initial `SELECT`.

Comment: There is no CTE in your question. Plus: the `full outer join` will return **all** rows from **both** tables - that can't really be optimized. The database has to read all rows from foo and all rows from bar.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the CTE is listed in my current approach; my question is, is there a better way to join on range types to return results consistent with the pattern in the desired result set?

Comment: If you want help with a slow query,post the real query you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - question updated with query

Comment: I don't see any indexes in your question? Is that a shortcoming in your question or in your setup? I also don't see a query plan. Consider instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I left it out of the example... a `gist` index is present on each `TSTZRANGE`

Comment: What you want is *basically* impossible: the carthesian product of foo(N=2) and bar(N=2) has size 4. The result of `range_a NOT IN range_b` can be 0,1 or 2 ranges, and the result of `tuple*tuple` can be 0 or 1 tuples. So, either you have to treat the split-ranges separately, or you'll have to "step through the boundaries" like @byMike does.

Comment: Something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/279da4/5) may help (but note, it won't work on containing ranges). And yeah, the overlaps operator (`&&`) can't be used for `full join` right now `FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions`, which leaves little room for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

### assumptions

- changing data structure is not an option
- timespans have a proper index

### optimization goals

- less data in cte queries
- simplify query
- "lazy" load data

### process steps

- generate a list of (unique) breakpoints
- compile a list of ranges between breakpoints
- load data matching the ranges

### resulting query

```
WITH
  eventlist AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      UNNEST(
          ARRAY [
          LOWER( active_timespan ),
          UPPER( active_timespan )
          ]
      ) AS timestamp
    FROM foo WHERE active_timespan && $1
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT
      UNNEST(
          ARRAY [
          LOWER( active_timespan ),
          UPPER( active_timespan )
          ]
      ) AS timestamp
    FROM bar WHERE bar.active_timespan && $2
  ),
  durations AS (
    SELECT
      TSTZRANGE(
          timestamp,
          LEAD( timestamp, 1, 'infinity' ) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC)
      ) AS active_span
    FROM eventlist
  )
SELECT
  durations.active_span,
  foo.foo,
  bar.bar
FROM durations
  LEFT JOIN foo ON active_span && foo.active_timespan
  LEFT JOIN bar ON active_span && bar.active_timespan
WHERE (foo.foo IS NOT NULL OR bar.bar IS NOT NULL)
  AND foo.active_timespan && $1
  AND bar.active_timespan && $2
;
```

Comment: This looks like it does the same thing as my current configuration except it hits the base tables twice (and the final table joins are written differently)... am I missing something?

Comment: the difference is, only the list timestamps are loaded into the memory first, not the whole tables --> less memory required. as I see now, the last two where statements are redundant. If there are proper indexes on all the ranges, this should work pretty fast.